# Android custom view Path circle part

Tags: java, android, path, draw

I have been trying to create a custom view [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAcJz.png)

My code

```
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
    float radius = getFloat(20);
    CornerPathEffect corEffect = new CornerPathEffect(radius);
    paint.setPathEffect(corEffect);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.reset();
    float top = getFloat(5);
    path.moveTo(0, top);
    float d = 80;
    path.lineTo((getWidth() - getFloat(d)) / 2, top);
    RectF oval = new RectF((getWidth() - getFloat(d)) / 2, top, (getWidth() + getFloat(d)) / 2, getFloat(d/2));
    path.arcTo(oval, 90, 360, false);

    path.lineTo((getWidth() + getFloat(d)) / 2, top);
    path.lineTo(getWidth(), top);
    path.lineTo(getWidth(), getHeight());
    path.lineTo(0, getHeight());
    path.close();

    paint.setShadowLayer(12, 0, 0, Color.argb(255, 200, 200, 200));
    setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

[and my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH0KO.png)

how to make the pit more round [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAcJz.png) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Path.cubicTo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path#cubicTo(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float))** to achieve what you want. Or by using **Path.ovalTo()** twice in symmetric manner.

```
Path.cubicTo(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx Faisal,
I try ovalTo

```
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
    float radius = getFloat(0);
    CornerPathEffect corEffect = new CornerPathEffect(radius);
    paint.setPathEffect(corEffect);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.reset();
    float top = getFloat(5);
    float round = getFloat(20);
    path.moveTo(0, getHeight());
    path.lineTo(0, round);
    path.cubicTo(0, top + round,
            0, top,
            round, top);

    float d = 80;
    path.lineTo(((getWidth() - getFloat(d)) / 2) - round, top);

    path.cubicTo(((getWidth() - getFloat(d)) / 2) - round, top,
            (getWidth() - getFloat(d)) / 2, top,
            (getWidth() - getFloat(d)) / 2, top + round);

    path.cubicTo((getWidth() - getFloat(d)) / 2, top,
            (getWidth() - getFloat(d)) / 2, getFloat(d/2),
            getWidth() / 2, getFloat(d/2));

    //-------------------

    path.cubicTo(getWidth() / 2, getFloat(d/2),
            (getWidth() + getFloat(d)) / 2, getFloat(d/2),
            (getWidth() + getFloat(d)) / 2, top);

    path.cubicTo((getWidth() + getFloat(d)) / 2, top + round,
            (getWidth() + getFloat(d)) / 2, top,
            ((getWidth() + getFloat(d)) / 2) + round, top);

    path.lineTo(((getWidth() + getFloat(d)) / 2) + round, top);
    path.lineTo(getWidth() - round, top);
    path.cubicTo(getWidth() - round, top,
            getWidth(), top,
            getWidth(), top + round);

    path.lineTo(getWidth(), getHeight());
    path.lineTo(0, getHeight());
    path.close();

    paint.setShadowLayer(12, 0, 0, Color.argb(255, 200, 200, 200));
    setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

but i see [artefacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KFpe.png)

I don't understand where the error is